# Project Euler - # 6 in python

Tags: python-2.7

So I just recently discovered project euler which is awesome for experimenting and getting practice in a programming language. I just recently figured out the answer for question 6, but I feel like it's such an ugly and inelegant way to be done.

The question asks:

The sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers is,
1**2 + 2**2 + ... + 10**2 = 385

The square of the sum of the first ten natural numbers is,
(1 + 2 + ... + 10)**2 = 552 = 3025

Hence the difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers and the square of the sum is 3025 − 385 = 2640.

Find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first one hundred natural numbers and the square of the sum.

My code looks like the following:

```
def sum_sq(value):
    count = value + 1
    while count > 0:
        sum_sq = []
        for x in range(count):
            sum_sq.append(x**2)
            count = count - 1
        sum_sq = sum(p)

    count1 = value + 1
    while count1 > 0:
        sq_sum = []
        for i in range(count1):
            sq_sum.append(i)
            count1 = count1 - 1
        sq_sum = sum(sq_sum)**2
    return sq_sum - sum_sq


>>> sum_sq(10)
2640
>>> sum_sq(100)
25502115
```

Do you folks have any suggestions to make this a little shorter and efficient? I'm relatively new to python so forgive me. I want to learn good coding techniques and not get into the habit of writing bad code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To paste code on Stack Overflow, copy and paste exactly what you have, highlight all of it, and click the `{}` code formatting button.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't mix spaces and tabs. Your indentation is screwed up. Use spaces only.

Comment: And you obviously don't need to build any lists to answer the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe did you type that yourself or is there a flag for codereview.stackexchange I can't seem to find?

Comment: @TimCastelijns the former!

Comment: @jonrsharpe :-( we need more options to flag for 'belongs on network X'

Comment: Another solution is to use the math properties where sum of squares = (n * n * n)/3 + (n * n)/2 + n/6  and square_of_sum = ( ( n * (n+1) ) / 2  ) ^2

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
def sum_sq(value):
    # list of product of all unique pairs (ignoring order)  
    # of numbers in the range 1 to value, both included
    t = [i*j for i in range(1, value) for j in range(i+1, value+1)]
    return 2 * sum(t)
```

That's because

```
(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)^2 - (1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2)
= 2(
    1*2 + 1*3 + ... + 1*n +
    2*3 + 2*4 + ... + 2*n +
    ...                   +
    ...                   +
    (n-1)*n  
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem a long time ago, also in Python. Some tips:

- You don't need to save every value in a list to answer the question. That is huge time-waster.
- It is possible to get the answer using only 1 while/for-loop instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

1 line code, does this work for you?

```
def sum_sq(n):
    return sum([i for i in range(n+1)])**2-sum([i**2 for i in range(n+1)])
>>> sum_sq(10)
2640
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `[]` brackets within the `sum` calls for better efficiency (this is Project Euler after all ;-) )